# Convert List<String[]> to int[]

Tags: java

If it's possible to convert arraylist of string `(ArrayList<String[]>)` to array of integer `(int[])`, is it possible to convert arraylist of arrays of string`(ArrayList<String[]>)` to array of integer `(int[])`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Your title and question don't match. Is it List<String[]> or List<String> ?

Comment: @NickJ read carefully, question makes sense, but shows no effort

Comment: An `ArrayList<String[]>` is 2-dimensional, but you want to convert it into `int[]` which is only 1 dimensional. In addition to parsing String to int, you'll need a mapping from 2D to 1D.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we know a question is solved when you accept an answer (as you have done with Pratswinz's answer).There's no need to edit the title of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have modified the code according to your edited answer,do reply if this is what you want.

```
 import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;


    class Ideone
    {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            ArrayList<String[]> strArrayList= new ArrayList<String[]>();
            String[] str1={"16","1421","1577"};

            String[] str2={"15","1451","1461","6556"};

            String[] str3={"157","8751","1136","556","879"};

            strArrayList.add(str1);
            strArrayList.add(str2);
            strArrayList.add(str3);


            int sizeOfArr=0;
            int i=0;

            for (String[] s : strArrayList)
            {

                sizeOfArr+=s.length;
            }

            int[] ArrayRes = new int[sizeOfArr];


            for (String[] s : strArrayList)
            {
                if(s.length>0){
                    for (String s1 : s){
                        ArrayRes[i] = Integer.parseInt(s1);
                        System.out.println(ArrayRes[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: my above answer is code version of @NickJ  explained above in comment to your question

Comment: Thank you Pratswinz! It's working, this is what I need. At least I have 2 solution from you and @NickJ

Answer (score 9):

In Java 8:

```
list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

---

## edit

Since the question was edited with `List<String[]>` instead of `List<String>`, a solution would be:

```
list.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

run the below code,i hope it meets you requirement.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<String> strArrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
            strArrayList.add("1");
            strArrayList.add("11");
            strArrayList.add("111");
            strArrayList.add("12343");
            strArrayList.add("18475");
        int[] ArrayRes = new int[strArrayList.size()];

        int i = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (String s : strArrayList)
        {

            ArrayRes[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);
            System.out.println(ArrayRes[i]);
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
11
111
12343
18475
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but not this that I need. My question is if ArrayList<String[]> can be converted to int[]

Comment: yah, I didn't recheck it before. Anyway thanks! If you have solution, I'll be happy cz I couldn't find any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment, you'll need to work out how to map from 2D to 1D array.

Here's a suggestion which results in `Integer[]` rather than `int[]` but you might not worry about that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String[]> arrList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    //fill it
    arrList.add(new String[] {"11","12","13","14","15"});
    arrList.add(new String[] {"21","22","23","24","25"});
    arrList.add(new String[] {"31","32","33","34","35"});
    arrList.add(new String[] {"41","42","43","44","45"});
    arrList.add(new String[] {"41","52","53","54","55"});

    //convert it
    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String[] array : arrList) {
        for (String str : array) {
            ints.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
        }
    }

    Integer[] result = ints.toArray(new Integer[] {});

    for (int i : result)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @NickJ, so we should map it using ArrayList<Integer>, this is my mistake that's why. Anyway I learn something from you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if all the Strings can be parsed to integers correctly.

Iterate over the list and in the list over the array. Parse the Strings to Integers (e.g. with `Integer.parseInt(someString);`) and store the integervalues in the integer array.

Of course you'll have to find the total number of values in the list to initialize the array.